# Embedding Power BI into Salesforce, Adding Controllers

Tags: oauth, controller, powerbi, salesforce, powerbi-embedded

I need to embed power BI in Salesforce. I am following [this guide](https://powerbi.microsoft.com/en-cy/blog/embedding-a-power-bi-report-into-salesforce/), but I am confused with the adding OAuthController and PowerBI controllers step. The PowerBIController hyperlink does not work and I cannot find much on OAuthController. Where could I find good examples of these, or does anyone have one to share?

Thank you in advance :)

Answer (score 1):

Follow this documentation on Embed PowerBI Content in salesforce both for Embed for your customers and Organisation. Also refer to the github sample code of Embedding PowerBI content.

References:

https://learn.microsoft.com/power-bi/developer/embedded/embed-power-bi-salesforce
https://github.com/PowerBiDevCamp/SalesforceAppOwnsDataEmbedding
https://github.com/PowerBiDevCamp/SalesforceUserOwnsDataEmbedding